# Invalid request, post must use JSON when using Postman

Tags: json, post, postman

I'm trying to log into a website and using Postman to work out the POST.

The url is https://vaxmgmt.force.com/authorizedEnroller/s/login/?ec=302&startURL=%2FauthorizedEnroller%2Fs%2F

The html for the username and password are:

[image]

[image: Password]

And the submit button:

[image: Log in]

I have in the headers "Content-Type" "application/json"
In the body/raw I have {"username":"username","password":"password"}
with a valid username and password

The headers that come back are:
[image]

Then I get "Invalid request, post must use JSON"

I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you select JSON as body type? It's on the right from radiobuttons with "none", "form-data", "raw"... and then a dropdown that has JSON as an option.
[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBNXZ.png)

p.s. Also, you said you used `"Content-Type" "application/jason"` - are you sure you didn't make a typo in `json` here? Please double check that just in case :)

Comment: Yes I did use JSON as the body type. And I just made a typo in this post I'll correct it here